# Swift Array flatmap

Tags: swift

This is a simplified representation of my problem using Realm database.

```
struct Foo: CustomStringConvertible {
    var fooId: Int
    var fooName: String
    var bars: [String]

    var description: String {
        return "Foo: \(fooId) \(fooName) \(bars)"
    }
}

var ff = [Foo]()

var f1 = Foo(fooId: 1, fooName: "A", bars: ["A1", "A2", "A3"])
var f2 = Foo(fooId: 2, fooName: "B", bars: ["B1"])
var f3 = Foo(fooId: 3, fooName: "A", bars: ["A4", "A5"])
var f4 = Foo(fooId: 4, fooName: "B", bars: ["B2", "B3", "B4"])
var f5 = Foo(fooId: 5, fooName: "B", bars: ["B5"])
var f6 = Foo(fooId: 6, fooName: "A", bars: ["A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10"])
var f7 = Foo(fooId: 7, fooName: "C", bars: ["C1", "C2", "C3"])

ff.append(contentsOf: [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7])
```

I want to flatMap or compactMap the Foo array based on fooName, so I'm able to construct a Map of fooName -> bars

> A -> ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10"] 
>   B -> ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"] 
>   C -> ["C1", "C2", "C3"]

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @Magnas I'm going to post another question regarding my Realm issue soon. The answer in this post works for Swift arrays, and it's exactly what I asked for, but I'm unable to apply it to Realm objects as there is no support for Dictionary and grouping.

Comment: @Magnas please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182360/swift-group-realm-query-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fairly straightforward:

```
// group instances by fooName
let dict: Dictionary<String, [Foo]> = Dictionary(grouping: ff, by: { $0.fooName })
print(dict)
// flat map the [Foo] instances to [String] of their bars
let dict2: Dictionary<String, [String]> = dict.mapValues { foos in foos.flatMap { $0.bars } }
print(dict2)
```

or simplified:

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: ff, by: { $0.fooName })
    .mapValues { foos in foos.flatMap { $0.bars } }
print(dict)
```

Comment: Cheers Sulthan, I'll try to apply your solution on my Realm objects tomorrow and hopefully it should do the trick.

Comment: @Rob Thanks to your input, I wanted to be be more explicit about the types and somehow I thought `flatMap` returns a `Sequence`.

Answer (score 4):

You can [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce):

```
let results = ff.reduce(into: [String: [String]]()) { result, foo in
    result[foo.fooName, default: []].append(contentsOf: foo.bars)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly modify your answer so the expected result is a dictionary of [Foo] type arrays
A -> [Foo(fooId: 1, fooName: "A", bars: ["A1", "A2", "A3"]), Foo(fooId: 3, fooName: "A", bars: ["A4", "A5"]), Foo(fooId: 6, fooName: "A", bars: ["A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10"])]
B -> [Foo(fooId: 2, fooName: "B", bars: ["B1"]), Foo(fooId: 4, fooName: "B", bars: ["B2", "B3", "B4"]), Foo(fooId: 5, fooName: "B", bars: ["B5"])]
C -> [Foo(fooId: 7, fooName: "C", bars: ["C1", "C2", "C3"])]

Comment: let results = ff.reduce(into: [String: [Foo]](), { (result, foo) in
    result[foo.fooName, default: []].append(foo)
})
Think this is doing the job. Now I've to tweak the way it's filtered and sorted

Comment: @Amitoj - Personally, if you wanted that, I’d do `let result = Dictionary(grouping: ff) { $0.fooName }`. But, with no offense, that’s not what you asked for in your question. You asked for values that are flattened arrays of `bars`, and my answer shows how to do that with a single call to `reduce(into:_:)` rather than the three calls that Sulthan's answer (+1) does. And I wouldn’t personally advise changing the question at this point because (a) that would invalidate both of our answers; and (b) you already know the answer to that question already (lol).