# Swift group Realm query results

Tags: swift, realm

I've following Realm objects (init and other non-essential properties removed for brevity) in my Swift app

```
@objcMembers
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

@objcMembers
class Project: Object {
    dynamic var projectId: Int = 0
    dynamic var manager: Person?
    var tasks = List<Task>()
    dynamic var lastTask: Task?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "projectId"
    }
}

@objcMembers
class Task : Object {
    dynamic var project = LinkingObjects(fromType: Project.self, property: "tasks")
    dynamic var taskId: String = ""
    dynamic var description: String = ""
    dynamic var createDate: Date = Date()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "taskId"
    }
}
```

So if there are 2 project members

> Person(id: 1, name: "Foo")
>
> Person(id: 2, name: "Bar")

and multiple projects,

> Project(projectId: 100, manager: , messages: [a1, a2, a3],
>   lastMessage: )
>
> a1 = Task(project: <#100>, taskId: "a1", description: "Task 1 about
>   project 100", createDate: Date() )
>
> a2 = Task(project: <#100>, taskId: "a2", description: "Task 2 about
>   project 100", createDate: Date() )
>
> a3 = Task(project: <#100>, taskId: "a3", description: "Task 3 about
>   project 100", createDate: Date() )
>
> Project(projectId: 101, manager: , messages: [a1, a2, a3],
>   lastMessage: )
>
> b1 = Task(project: <#101>, taskId: "b1", description: "Task 1 about
>   project 101", createDate: Date() )
>
> b2 = Task(project: <#101>, taskId: "b2", description: "Task 2 about
>   project 101", createDate: Date() )
>
> b3 = Task(project: <#101>, taskId: "b3", description: "Task 3 about
>   project 101", createDate: Date() )
>
> b4 = Task(project: <#101>, taskId: "b3", description: "Task 3 about
>   project 101", createDate: Date() )
>
> Project(projectId: 102, manager: , messages: [a1, a2, a3],
>   lastMessage: )
>
> c1 = Task(project: <#102>, taskId: "c1", description: "Task 1 about
>   project 102", createDate: Date() )
>
> Project(projectId: 103, manager: , messages: [a1, a2, a3],
>   lastMessage: )
>
> d1 = Task(project: <#103>, taskId: "d1", description: "Task 1 about
>   project 103", createDate: Date() )
>
> d2 = Task(project: <#103>, taskId: "d2", description: "Task 2 about
>   project 103", createDate: Date() )
>
> d3 = Task(project: <#103>, taskId: "d3", description: "Task 3 about
>   project 103", createDate: Date() )

In my ProjectsViewController

I can get my Realm results as

```
func getProjects() -> Results<Project> {
    let results: Results<Conversation> = database
        .objects(Conversation.self)
        .sorted(byKeyPath: "lastTask.createDate", ascending: false)

    return results
}
```

*[Side note - If there is a better way of sorting the results based on last item of tasks List then do let me know. That'll make the use lastTask var redundant.]*

which will display in my table view as

```
===================
Projects
-------------------
Foo 
Project 100
Task a3 
-------------------
Bar 
Project 101
Task b4
-------------------
Foo
Project 102
Task c1 
-------------------
Bar
Project 103
Task d3 
-------------------
```

Question: How do I group the results in Realm query so I get a dictionary of grouped Array of results, such as

> Foo -> [Project 100, Array of Tasks], [Project 102, Array of Tasks]
>
> Bar -> [Project 101, Array of Tasks], [Project 103, Array of Tasks]

and they're tracked via NotificationToken for all inserts / updates. Also I want to dislay them grouped by sections in the table view.

```
===================
Projects (Grouped)
-------------------
Foo (Section Header)
-------------------
Project 100
Task a3 
-------------------
Project 102
Task c1 
-------------------


-------------------
Bar (Section Header)
-------------------
Project 101
Task b4
-------------------
Project 103
Task d3 
-------------------
```

Comment: `dynamic var lastTask: Task?` may be problematic as Realm cannot manage user defined objects. Are you expecting it to in this case? Also on this *a dictionary of grouped Array of results* can you clarify what the key: value pairs would be in the dictionary? It's a bit unclear from the question.

Comment: Also, there is no `Conversation.self` object in your code... how does that correlate to the questions? Also, why do results need to be grouped? If you know an object has a section of Foo as as the section header, it would be added to that section in the tableview via the tableView delegate methods.

Comment: Use .distinct(by: [""]) available in Realm 3.1 and later. Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751597/11611421

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer based on what I *think* you're asking.

If I understand correctly, you want to find a dictionary with the `Person` as the key, the values being a dictionary with Project ID (or Project) as the key and values of an array of tasks. i.e.

```
let result : [Person:[Project:[Task]]] = .....
```

If this isn't correct, you can probably take the ideas here and massage them into your ideal.

As you want to key by Person, I'd add a reverse lookup property to the `Person` class - and this is probably the main thing you're missing. Look at this section of the manual for guidance: (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships), and then add this property to `Person`:

```
let projects = LinkingObjects(fromType: Project.self, property: "manager")
```

I would then add a computed property to `Person` to retrieve the projects and tasks. This creates an array since that was asked for in the question.

```
var projectsAndTasks : [Project:[Task]]
{
  var result : [Project:[Task]] = [:]
  for project in projects
  {
    result[project] = project.tasks.map { $0 }
  }

  return result
}
```

If you want the tasks to be sorted, then add a computed property to `Projects` called sortedTasks that does that for you.

Once that's done, you can add a function somewhere (either global or static to `Person`) to add the results for all objects of `Person` into a single dictionary. E.g. :

```
extension Realm
{
  var allPersonsAndProjects : [Person:[Project:[Task]]]
  {
    var result : [Person:[Project:[Task]]] = []
    let persons = objects(Person.self)
    for person in persons
    {
      result[person] = person.projectsAndTasks
    }

    return result
  }
}
```

Forgive any compile errors.